Skylab's Boom during EVA
Does anyone know what is this silver boom that is moved to the upper left corner of this YouTube video?
I would like to know more details on this.


The video identifies this as the second spacewalk of Skylab 3.

On August 24, Garriott and Lousma stepped outside for the second EVA of the mission, replacing ATM film canisters and installing a cable for a new set of gyroscopes they mounted inside the station.

The NTRS has a paper on EVA tooling, which mentions a film transfer boom. They used this to move photographic film canisters (the block on the end of the pole) to and from the Apollo Telescope Mount.

Another video shows this pole also as part of EVA 2.
Skylab 3 documentary
